# android.view.WindowLeaked: error showing when alert dialog using

Tags: android

I have tried dismiss the alert dialog when the activity is destroyed.

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

But I still got an error:

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp.activities.SignInActivity has leaked window DecorView@60f300f[] that was originally added here
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:424)
     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
     at com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp.activities.SignInActivity.getFingerPrint(SignInActivity.java:713)
     at com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp.activities.SignInActivity$8.onClick(SignInActivity.java:428)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

here is my activity:

```
if(AccountUtils.getIsTouch().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
    checkTouchId.setChecked(true);
    checkTouchId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtTouchId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        //Fingerprint API only available on from Android 6.0 (M)
        keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
        getFingerPrint();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Device does not have a Fingerprint Sensor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} else {
    getFingerPrintHardware();
}
```

I'm getting error in below method : in this I'm using two alert dialogs .

```
 public void getFingerPrint(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if(!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()){
            /**
             * An error message will be displayed if the device does not contain the fingerprint hardware.
             * However if you plan to implement a default authentication method,
             * you can redirect the user to a default authentication activity from here.
             * Example:
             * Intent intent = new Intent(this, DefaultAuthenticationActivity.class);
             * startActivity(intent);
             */
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Device does not have a Fingerprint Sensor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //textView.setText("Your Device does not have a Fingerprint Sensor");
        } else {
            // Checks whether fingerprint permission is set on manifest
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //textView.setText("Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else{
                // Check whether at least one fingerprint is registered
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignInActivity.this,R.style.DialogLevelsStyle);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Touch ID isn't Set Up on This Device");
                        TextView myMsg = new TextView(this);
                        myMsg.setText("To set up Touch ID on this decice, go to Settings > Touch id & Passcode and add a valid fingerprint");
                        myMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                        myMsg.setPadding(20,50,20,0);
                        myMsg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        myMsg.setTextSize(15);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(myMsg);
                        //alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please place your fingertip on the scanner to verify your identity and Login");
                        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //finish();
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                            }
                        });

                        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();

                        //textView.setText("Register at least one fingerprint in Settings");
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Register at least one fingerprint in Settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else{
                        // Checks whether lock screen security is enabled or not
                        if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
                            //textView.setText("Lock screen security not enabled in Settings");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Lock screen security not enabled in Settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignInActivity.this,R.style.DialogLevelsStyle);
                            alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.fingerprint);
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Touch Id for FOREWARN");
                            TextView myMsg = new TextView(this);
                            if(hiddenEmail == null){
                                myMsg.setText("Sign In with User Id "+userName);
                            }else {
                                myMsg.setText("Sign In with User Id "+hiddenEmail);
                            }

                            myMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                            myMsg.setPadding(10,50,10,0);
                            myMsg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                            myMsg.setTextSize(16);
                            alertDialogBuilder.setView(myMsg);
                            //alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please place your fingertip on the scanner to verify your identity and Login");
                            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //finish();
                                    Constant.isCanceled = "true";
                                }
                            });

                            alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();

                            generateKey();

                            if (cipherInit()) {
                                FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
                                FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
                                helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I already added `onDestroy` method which is calling `dailog.dismiss()`. 
I'm confused to find out where I did wrong. Please help me.

Comment: show your full code.

Comment: can u please have a look at my updated code

Comment: Can you tell me what code is there at SignInActivity.java; Line number:713 ?

Comment: yes. in my getFingerPrint() method --> which is 2nd alertdialog.show() - 713 line

Answer (score 0):

> leaked window DecorView@60f300f[] that was originally added

- Above exceptions are coming if Dialogs are not **`dismiss()`** before
  **`Activity`** is ended.

Add this [**`onPause`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) section.

```
 @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

**Rectify**

```
 if (cipherInit()) {
                            FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
                            FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
                            helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
                        }
                            generateKey();
                            alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: actually my intention is when i came to signin page --> if the user already signed  with fingerprint it shows a pop up for touch id. so i need to show popup every time when i came to sign in activity, if already user setup touch id.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this issue happens when you are trying to show the dialog after your activity is destroyed, finished, onPause, ...

Some solutions:

- Check if you are not calling the `alertDialog.show();` in the same parent scope where you finish, pause or destroy your activity and try to control it.

  > for example, you've started another activity or process and then you try to show your dialog on the current activity
- You can check if the activity is finished before calling the dialog `if(!this.isFinishing()){//show your dialog}` `this` for `yourActivity`
- You can also use a small trick to check the state of your activity before starting a dialog. :

  > @Override protected void onPause() { isRunning = false; }
  >
  > @Override protected void onResume() { isRunning = true; }